# Is there a way to customize the default location for Templates in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to point the templates window to a shared folder so that a few different people can access it when logged in. It defaults to C:\users<USERNAME>\Appdata\roaming\microsoft\sql server management studio\14.0\templates.

I have come across similar questions, but the answers didn't work for me: [Change SSMS Default File Location (Specifically Templates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580089/change-ssms-default-file-location-specifically-templates)
-specifically, I tried editing the registry editor but couldn't get it to work.

I've also gone through several settings in SSMS and still can't find how to change this.

Comment: Use snippets instead. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2589/use-sql-server-code-snippets-to-encourage-consistent-conventions/?utm_source=AaronBertrand